# networkx extract ordering of topology

Tags: python, networkx

i want to group a network of nodes by their connection. furthermore i want to index inside the subgroups.

i have pairs resembling connections between elements.
lets say i know  that

A->B, B->C, C->D, E->F, F->G.

1. i want to destinguish the two distinct networks, e.g.

A->B->C->D
E->F->G

input:

```
import networkx as nx

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"source": ["A", "B", "C", "E", "F"], "destination": ["B", "C", "D", "F", "G"]}
)

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(df.source.append(df.destination).unique())
G.add_edges_from(df.to_records(False))
groups = list(nx.algorithms.components.connected_components(G))
df["group"] = [
    groups.index(group)
    for element in df.source
    for group in groups
    if element in group
]
df
```

output:

```
    source  destination group
0   A   B   0
1   B   C   0
2   C   D   0
3   E   F   1
4   F   G   1
```

2. furthermore i want to extract an index that follows the ordering and topology of the pairs, so that the nodes are numbered from one side to the other.

desired output:

```
    source  destination group index
0   A   B   0   0
1   B   C   0   1
2   C   D   0   2
3   E   F   1   0
4   F   G   1   1
```

no circular networks are possible in my data.

any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Nodes can be ordered using [`topological_sort`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.topological_sort.html)

```
for group in groups:
    subgraph = nx.subgraph(G, group)
    node_order = nx.topological_sort(subgraph)
```

In general, edges cannot be sorted unambiguously in the same way, unless each subgraph in your graph is indeed a chain (as in your toy example). In that case, you can then convert the node order into a sorted list of edges using:

```
edge_order = list(zip(node_order[:-1], node_order[1:]))
```

Comment: thank you for your proposed solution. however its not working right away. when i want to get the node_order via `list(node_order)` it throws: `NetworkXError: Topological sort not defined on undirected graphs.`  When i change `nx.Graph` to `nx.DiGraph`, it throws an `not implemented for directed type` error at `groups = list(nx.algorithms.components.connected_components(G))`. some more advice on that?

Comment: You could create the graph as a directed graph (`DiGraph`), and make an undirected copy for computing the components.

Comment: thank you @Paul, it made  'click', see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72228402/4964095 -- should i see the notification of your name somehow formatted? i dont... --

Comment: What does `groups` contain here?

Comment: @alper Refers to a variable in OPs question: `groups = list(nx.algorithms.components.connected_components(G))`.

Answer (score 0):

@Paul as well as [the docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html) led me to the solution. Thank you very much!

(I slightly changed the ordering of rows in the example)

```
# %%
import networkx as nx

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"source": ["B", "A", "C", "E", "F"], "destination": ["C", "B", "D", "F", "G"]}
)

# generate both directed and undirected graph
G = nx.Graph()
NG = nx.DiGraph()

for graph in G, NG:
    graph.add_nodes_from(df.source.append(df.destination).unique())
    graph.add_edges_from(df.to_records(False))

# task 1: get distinct path groups (usage of G)
groups = list(nx.algorithms.components.connected_components(G))
df["group"] = [
    groups.index(group) for element in df.source for group in groups if element in group
]

# task 2: get within path index (usage of NG)
# roots = (v for v, d in NG.in_degree() if d == 0)
# leaves = [v for v, d in NG.out_degree() if d == 0]
# all_paths = []
# for root in roots:
#     paths = nx.all_simple_paths(NG, root, leaves)
#     all_paths.extend(paths)
# all_paths

# use paul brodersen more elegant code to feed a list
all_paths = []
for group in groups:
    subgraph = nx.subgraph(NG, group)
    node_order = nx.topological_sort(subgraph)
    all_paths.append(list(node_order))

path_index = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in all_paths]).reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'path_index', 0:'source'})
df = df.merge(path_index, on = 'source')

df
```

gives me

```
    source  destination group   path_index
0   B   C   0   1
1   A   B   0   0
2   C   D   0   2
3   E   F   1   0
4   F   G   1   1
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested the script with real world data, and as it is more messy than the play data, i wont get the output i like. Lets say i have got this

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'A'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'L'), ('D', E'), ('D', 'F'), ('E', 'D'), ('E', 'G'), ('F', 'D'), ('F', 'J'), ('G', 'E'), ('G', K'), ('H', 'I'), ('I', 'H'), ('I', 'J'), ('J', 'F'), ('J', 'I'), ('K', 'G'), ('L', C'), ('M', 'N'), ('N', 'M'), ('N', 'O'), ('O', 'N'), ('O', 'P'), ('P', 'O'), ('P', Q'), ('Q', 'P'), ('Q', 'R'), ('R', 'Q'), ('S', 'T'), ('T', 'S')],, columns=['source','destination'])
```

drawed as

[image: example_network]

Although grouping works, the inner group index wont.

It throws

```
raise nx.NetworkXUnfeasible(
    "Graph contains a cycle or graph changed during iteration"
)
```

I know that in the data, A->B as well as B->A is present, therefore the cycle error.

My first idea was to remove the duplicated lines, but how would i know whether i can keep one or the other?

At the lower left, we see:
If L->C and C->A, i got rows for C->L and A->C as well in the data.
Therefore after dups removal i could end up with C->L and C->A, but what i want is the real path of L->C and C->A. It seems to identify the path and index from it, i have to know the path beforehand for dups removal?

Is this complicated or am i thinking just too complicated?

NB: `nx.topological_sort(subgraph)` does not do what i think it would do. It does not care about the path, leading to `'A', 'B', 'C', 'L'` for the lower left, instead of `'B', 'A', 'C', 'L'`. But the docs clearly state `This ordering is valid only if the graph has no directed cycles.` RTFM